# Using views how to display taxonomy term description in D6?

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

How can I display taxonomy term description next to taxonomy term in a views field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new view of the type 'Term'. (D6: Select Term radio button while adding new view, D7: Choose Taxononomy Terms in 'Show' select box)

Then choose the fields

```
Taxonomy: Term Term
Taxonomy: Term description
```

that's it, and you can choose  a suitable Style for the display

Comment: Thanks Anoop,
But I have to display term description on 'View type:Node', i have an option to print the term description but the field is always blank, though if I have the content.

Comment: i able to get term and term description on 'View type:Node', also,  but only when the term have already selected for any node

Comment: Yes, the term is selected for all the nodes, but for some reason the description is not being displayed :(

Comment: what are the filters used in view?

Comment: In fact, I have multiple taxonomy terms from multiple vocabularies selected for every node, and one of the taxonomy term has term description mentioned.

Comment: Filters used are: [Node: Type], [Node: Published], [Taxonomy: Term]

Comment: The other way to display term description in your case is, add a php code field with some query. You can just write a query to get taxonomy description by passing term id. The table is ' `term_data`

Comment: right, but views fields dose not support PHP code due to security reasons.

Comment: Have you didnt used http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield module , Install this module. Choose term id in views field, and exclude it from display. Then add custom php field which is get from above module and simply add the folowing code echo db_result(db_query("SELECT description FROM {term_data} WHERE tid = %d ", $data->term_data_tid));

Comment: I finally got it working without views_customfield, I had two filters enabled, so I had to reorder the filters.